# MongoDB 3.4 - Add nodes to Replica Set when only one is available

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.4

I originally had a Replica Set comprised of three nodes on different servers. As part of a contingency plan, I tested how long it would take to hot-swap from using a replica set to only using one node, in case one of our data servers went offline.

I followed the steps listed in the Mongo docs here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/remove-replica-set-member/

I manually removed the others nodes from the cfg.members array and performed a `rs.conf()` to get the other node working properly. This seemed like the fastest way to restore our application, with writes being possible again after ~7 minutes of downtime.

Now, I'm at the point where I have one node in the replica set, with unsynced writes, and I need to add the other two nodes back. How do I go about adding these two nodes, while maintaining the writes committed during the hot-swap? I can't just execute `rs.conf()` since I am unable to hold elections in my replica set. I apologize if this question is a duplicate, but I was unable to find any satisfactory answers.

Comment: One by one `rs.add("hostname:port")` at current PRIMARY.

Comment: Can u share the current `rs.status()` output?